# ValueError: invalid literal for float(): "320" for a normal string

Tags: python

I just encountered a very strange problem: I try to turn a string to float and then back to str  by this:

```
str(float(tmp[1])/100) # tmp[1] contain the str
```

But it throw out `ValueError: invalid literal for float(): "320"`

So i try this:

```
            try:
                line_split[list_index] = str(float(tmp[1])/100)
            except:
                print >> sys.stderr, repr(tmp[1])
```

Also, the same error, and print `'"320"'`

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Only digits/decimal points and trailing/leading whitespace are allowed in float literals (and a couple of miscellaneous things like `inf` and `NaN`. Quotation marks will throw an error.

Comment: Looks like the string content *includes the quotes*!?

Comment: But all the error messages and the print result shows the parameter pass to float is `320`

Comment: If `repr` gives you `'"320"'`, the actual string content is `"320"` (including quotes).

Comment: if the real content is `"320"` then, i think `float("320")` is totally leagal

Comment: That would be legal, yes; but it looks like you're actually doing `float('"302"')`.

Comment: Try this in the Python 2 REPL: `float("320a")` The response is `ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 320a`. Notice the distinct lack of quote marks in the error message. Python 3 is a little more helpful: the error message is `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '320a'`, and here we see Python using its preferred single quotes for the repr of a string.

Comment: `str(float(tmp[1][1:-1]/100)`

Comment: @deceze I got it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be some sort of non-printing character that's present in the value you are using. It looks like you're using Python 2.x, in which case you can check for them with this:

```
print repr(tmp[1])
```

You'll likely see something in there that's escaped in the form \x00. These non-printing characters don't show up when you print directly to the console, but their presence is enough to negatively impact the parsing of a string value into a float.